# How to convert an Object to array in php with framework Codeigniter

Tags: php

I trying to query in database, and the result is an Object. I want to show that result but $response always Null in my show.php. I using CodeIgniter

> My Controller

home.php

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
public function _contruct(){

    parent::_contruct();
}
public function index(){
    $this->load->view("from.html");
}
public function findID(){

    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $id = $this->input->post("findId"); 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM cli_articles WHERE ID='{$id}'";
    $response=$this->db->query($sql);  
    //$row=$response->row();
   // echo $row->name;
    $this->load->view("show",$response);
}
}
?>
```

> My view

from.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<header>From</header>
<body>
<form name="findID" action="findID" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="findId">
    <input type="submit" value="FindID">

</form>
</body>
```

and show.php

```
<?php 
while($show_db=mysql_fetch_array($response)){
?>
    <p> id : <?php echo $show_db['id'];?><br></p>                   
    <p> category_id :  <?php echo $show_db['category_id'];?><br></p>                  
    <p> content : <?php echo $show_db['content'];?><br></p>                     
    <p> created : <?php echo $show_db['created'];?><br></p>                   
    <p> description : <?php echo $show_db['description'];?><br></p>               
    <p> image :   <?php echo $show_db['image'];?><br></p>        
    <p> mt_description : <?php echo $show_db['mt_description'];?><br></p>                   
    <p> mt_keyword : <?php echo $show_db['mt_keyword'];?><br></p>     
    <p> name : <?php echo $show_db['name'];?><br></p>            
    <p> ngay_dang : <?php echo $show_db['ngay_dang'];?><br></p>                  
    <p> order :  <?php echo $show_db['order'];?><br></p>                
    <p> slug : <?php echo $show_db['slug'];?><br></p>                   
    <p> status : <?php echo $show_db['status'];?><br></p>                   
    <p> view :  <?php echo $show_db['view'];?><br></p>
    <?php                  
}   
?>
```

anh i don't know why `$show_db=mysql_fetch_array($response)` not correct
Thank for your help!

Comment: When passing data to views, it should be an associative array: `$this->load->view('show', ['response' => $response]);`. The key will be the variable name in the view. So if you pass: `['something' => 'foo']`, you can access it with: `<?= $something ?>` in your view (this would echo "foo").

Comment: Thank you! 
It's working 
but I have problem with while($show_db=mysql_fetch_array($response)) Message: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Comment: Here's how you use CI's database class: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html?highlight=query

Comment: Look at the above link. You're not getting a resource. You're getting a CI-result class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using codeigniter, you really should consider using it's 'active record':

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM cli_articles WHERE ID='{$id}'";
 $response=$this->db->query($sql);
```

I would instead suggest:

```
 $this->db->select('*'); 
 $this->db->where('id', $id); 
 $response = $this->db->get('cli_articles')->result_array(); // for array, result() for object, row() for a single result object, row_array() for a single array
```

But if you want to keep your style:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM cli_articles WHERE ID='{$id}'";
 $response=$this->db->query($sql);  
 $view_data['results'] = $response->result_array(); 
 $this->load->view("show",$view_data);
```

And in your view:

```
<?= $results['id']; // or you made need to loop, depending on your array structure ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the result_array method.

In your controller you can use CI's ActiveRecord syntax:

`$response = $this->db->where('ID', $id)->get('cli_articles');`

Then replace your while statement in your view with:

`foreach ($response->result_array() as $show_db) { ...`

Comment: it's useful thank you. can you help me. i tried alot this line not working while($show_db=mysql_fetch_array($response)) i dont know why

Comment: mysql_fetch_array is a different approach which uses PHP native mysql methods. If you use the framework to do the query, you should use the framework's methods to process the response, as in the code above